# Glide sometimes takes the whole Layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide, scaletype

Glide's behavior is unpredectable sometimes, while using the app sometimes the ImageView looks like this:
[image: screenshot]

Just going back (to the parent activity) and come back, without restarting the app, to the same movie result, it appears *fixed* (supposed appearance) like this:

[image: right ImageView]

I don't why I have this behavior, here the xml code for the image view:

```
<ImageView
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/poster_sample"
    android:id="@+id/poster_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Glide code:

```
Glide
    .with(getContext())
    .load(mMovieValues.get(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_POSTER_URL))
    .centerCrop()
    .into(mPoster);
```

Where is the problem? and how to fix that?

Comment: set maxHeight to your **ImageView**

Comment: @Amir still have the same behavior.

Comment: why your setting the image source in `ImageView` too while your telling Glide to load the it from `MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_POSTER_URL`?

Comment: @Anders poster url is stored in ContentValues object!

Answer (score 1):

You should give a fixed height and width to your `ImageView` and no need to use `centerCrop`

```
<ImageView
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/poster_sample"
    android:id="@+id/poster_image"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"/>
```

and remove `CenterCrop` from here too

```
Glide
.with(getContext())
.load(mMovieValues.get(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_POSTER_URL))
.into(mPoster);
```

Comment: This does the job, But poster's size might get changed, isn't there better way using Glide?

Comment: if you want a fixed size then you should do it this way, this is better but if you want to keep it to `wrape_content` then there won't be a fixed size for your `ImageView` and I don't think its a good idea